# Unable to call Javascript method

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to run following javascript loop but its not working:

```
function column_total()
  {
    alert("In column_total method");
    var row1val=0,row2val=0,row3val=0,row4val=0,row5val=7,row6val=0,row7val=0,row8val=0,row9val=0,row10val=0,row11val=0,row12val=0;
    for(i=1;i<=12;i++)
    {
        for(j=i;j<=i;j++)
        {
            alert("In j loop");
            row"+j+"val += parseFloat(document.getElementById('p'"+i+").value);
            row"+j+"val += parseFloat(document.getElementById('d'"+i+").value);
            row"+j+"val += parseFloat(document.getElementById('o'"+i").value);
            document.getElementById('t1').value=row"+i+"val;
        }
        var rowtotalval=row1val+row2val+row3val+row4val+row5val+row6val+row7val+row8val+row9val+row10val+row11val+row12val;
        return true;
    }
  }
```

In the html I am calling the code via `onfocus` attribute of textbox t1 and here is the html code:

```
<input type="text" name="p1" id="p1"></input>
<input type="text" name="p2" id="p2"></input>
<input type="text" name="d1" id="d1" ></input>
<input type="text" name="d2" id="d2" ></input>
<input type="text" name="o1" id="o1" ></input>
<input type="text" name="o2" id="o2" ></input>
<input type="text" name="t1" id="t1" onfocus="column_total()"></input>
```

Comment: What ?? you have a lot of error, what are you trying to do ?

Comment: Beyond the syntax errors, your function returns true on the first iteration of the outer loop... not entirely sure what you're actually trying to accomplish.

Comment: i suggest to use an array, instead of hard coded variable name, which can not (...) right accessed.

Comment: Please go through some basic tutorials in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use an array instead of `row"+j+"val`. This "dynamic" variable name  syntax you are trying to use doesn't exist.

For instance, you could use an array named `rowval` and assing values to it using `rowval[j] += parseFloat(document.getElementById('p'"+i+").value)` .

You could also do something analogous using `eval` or `this[row"+j+"val] += x` but I don't see any need of using anything different from the trivial array here.

Answer (score 1):

row"+j+"val - this is not correct for javascript